# python's subprocess.Popen skips input

Tags: python, subprocess

I've found that subprocess.Popen() will skip input bytes in a specific scenario.  To demonstrate the issue, I wrote the following (nonsensical) program:

```
import sys 
from subprocess import Popen

skip = int(sys.argv[1])
fin = sys.stdin
fin.read(skip)
cmd = 'wc -c'.split()
Popen(cmd, stdin=fin).wait()
```

This program skips the specified number of bytes of input, then shells out to `wc` to count the remaining bytes.

Now try out the program using `dd` to generate input:

```
# skipping 0, everything works fine:
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=100 2>/dev/null | python wc.py 0
100

$ # but skipping more than 0 yields an unexpected result.
$ # this should return 99:
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=100 2>/dev/null | python wc.py 1
0

$ # I noticed it skips up to the 4k boundary.
$ # this should return 8191:
$ dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 count=8192 2>/dev/null | python wc.py 1
4096
```

Can anyone explain this unexpected behavior?  A known issue?  A bug that should be filed?  A 'ur doin it wrong'?

FWIW, I ended up getting around the issue by using a pipe for stdin, then feeding in data one chunk at a time:

```
p = Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE)
chunk = fin.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
while chunk:
    p.stdin.write(chunk)
    chunk = fin.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
p.stdin.close()
p.wait()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.read()` function on `sys.stdin` is buffered inside Python. So when you read a byte, Python actually reads a whole buffer full, expecting that you're going to do the same thing again soon. However, reading a buffer full (4096 in your situation) means the OS thinks that input has already been read and won't pass it on to `wc`.

You can avoid this problem by using [`os.read()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.read) to skip the requisite number of input bytes. This calls the OS directly and does not buffer data within your process:

```
os.read(fin.fileno(), skip)
```

Comment: Great, I wasn't aware of `os.read()`.  Your answer led to me realizing that I could avoid buffering by re-opening stdin with `os.fdopen()`: `fin = os.fdopen(sys.stdin.fileno(), 'r', 0)`